# why do some ActiveSync commands work in Android Email application but not in standalone Java client?

Tags: android, activesync

I'm developing a Java Exchange ActiveSync client and I want to Sync the inbox folder to retrieve email headers. I followed the MS ActiveSync documentation and was able to authenticate, folderSync and sync with the server. However, only certain properties in the Sync command are working.

In order to test what *good* ActiveSync messages would look like, I used the Android Emulator plus CharlesProxy HTTP proxy to capture the ActiveSync messages sent from the Android Email application. I was able to catch and decode the WBXML messages successfully. I saw that ActiveSync XML messages that I had tried unsuccessfully to use worked fine from the 'built-in' email application. E.g.

This XML Sync command works when sent from the Email application, but not from my Java client:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>sync key here</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>collectionID HERE</CollectionId>
            <DeletesAsMoves/>
            <GetChanges/>
            <WindowSize>5</WindowSize>
            <Options>
                <FilterType>2</FilterType>
                <MIMESupport>2</MIMESupport>
                <MIMETruncation>7</MIMETruncation>
            </Options>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

Does anyone know why? Do some applications somehow have special privileges that mean they can use the full ActiveSync protocol?
I'd like to stress that I *can* run a successful Sync command like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Sync xmlns="AirSync">
    <Collections>
        <Collection>
            <Class>Email</Class>
            <SyncKey>sync key here</SyncKey>
            <CollectionId>collection Id here</CollectionId>
            <GetChanges/>
        </Collection>
    </Collections>
</Sync>
```

I just can't add the extra properties like the Android email app does.

Any help is appreciated!